# Make two random teams form dataset and get overall team score in R

Tags: r, random, dataset, subset

Lets say I have a soccer team of 10 players (players) from which I should make two subteams of 5 players each and then compute the overall score for each team.

```
players <- read.table(text=
"paul    3
ringo   3
george  5
john    5
mick    1
ron     2
charlie 3
ozzy    5
keith   3
brian   3", as.is=TRUE)
```

I've already extracted a random set of 5 players:

```
t1 <- sample(players$V1, size = 5)
```

But one it comes to create the second team (excluding the players in the first one) and calculating the overall score for both teams I'm completed blocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try sampling the indices of players to construct the first team instead of sampling the names.

```
idx1 <- sample(1:nrow(players), 5)
```

You can actually use these indices to grab all the information about each team:

```
team1 <- players[idx1,]
team2 <- players[-idx1,]
```

The score for each team can be computed with `sum(team1$V2)` and `sum(team2$V2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, you could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
##
(data.table(data)[
  ,team := sample(1:.N,.N) %% 2][
    ,list(
      score = sum(V2)), 
    by=team])
#      team  score
# 1:    0    14
# 2:    1    19
```

where a person's team is determined by whether their random draw is even or odd.

---

Or if you want to see the players assigned to each team,

```
(data.table(data)[
  ,team := sample(1:.N,.N) %% 2][
    ,list(
      score = sum(V2),
      players = V1), 
    by=team])
#      team  score  players
# 1:    0    17     paul
# 2:    0    17     john
# 3:    0    17     mick
# 4:    0    17     ozzy
# 5:    0    17     brian
# 6:    1    16     ringo
# 7:    1    16     george
# 8:    1    16     ron
# 9:    1    16     charlie
# 10:   1    16     keith
```

Answer (score 1):

First just get a random order.

```
> k <- sample(nrow(players))
```

Then to get the names in each team, put the list in that order and put it in two columns.

```
> matrix(players$V1[k], ncol=2)
##     [,1]    [,2]     
## [1,] "keith" "charlie"
## [2,] "paul"  "john"   
## [3,] "ron"   "brian"  
## [4,] "mick"  "george" 
## [5,] "ozzy"  "ringo"
```

To get the total, do the same thing with the scores and compute the column sums.

```
> colSums(matrix(players$V2[k], ncol=2))
## [1] 14 19
```